# Is it possible to pause the django background tasks?

Tags: django, django-models, background-task

For example I have a [`django background task`](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) like this.

```
notify_user(user.id, repeat=3600, repeat_until=2020-12-12 00:00:00)
```

Which will repeat every 1 hour until some datetime.

My question is :
Is it possible to *pause/resume* this task? (if not possible to resume then restart the task again would be fine also).

Is there someone who is experienced with django background tasks ?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a documented way of achieving this, but you can always delete the task from the DB.

For example:

```
from background_task.models import Task

task = notify_user(user.id, repeat=3600, repeat_until=2020-12-12 00:00:00)

instance = Task.objects.get(id=task.pk)
instance.delete()
```

Now just call the task again to restart it:

```
task = notify_user(user.id, repeat=3600, repeat_until=2020-12-12 00:00:00)
```

Comment: Yes I can delete the task. But I was wondering if there is also a possibility of pause/resume task.

Comment: @user12428848 There isn't a documented way to "pause/resume", but you can always delete, then start it again

Comment: Yes that would be fine also.